# How to run runTransactionBlock when there's no data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm kind of stuck and not sure how to proceed with this. I have an iOS app, written in swift. It's a social network app. It has posts, users, following, liking, etc.

The idea of the database hierarchy of a post is simple and yet, very efficient when the app grows in terms of users. Unless the "notes" button on the cell displaying that post data is tapped (which is connected to `notes` of the posts), no additional data is needed. Hence, I don't want to store all the likes, all the comments, etc under the post itself because each time a post is displayed, all the likes, comments, etc would be downloaded regardless if the user actually want to see them or not. I'd like to create a data mapping.  Here's my idea:

[image]

Now, say the very first user have created the very first post. It was no liked since it's brand new. No previous posts, no mapping table exist. It's all from scratch as it should be.

Here's what I can't understand how to do. I know that for things like likes, I have to use `runTransactionBlock` in case 1000 users like a post at the same time. The `notes` should be calculated based on sum of likes and comments. The action should look like this: the user likes a post:

- Their `uid` should added to `posts_likes` node
- The `likesCount` should be incremented by 1
- The `notes` count should be incremented by 1 (because of the `likesCount`) PS: `notes` should be incremented every time a user like, comment or repost anything.

I'm totally lost on how to even start that.

---

Comment: Read the Documentation... https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Comment: @Mark already did that. It wasn't that helpful because I think I need to run multiple `runtransactionBlock`s